# How to adjust a pressure regulator, that doesn't have a screw/bolt?

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure

The pressure in my house seems to have dropped, so I called my City Water department. They came out and tested it, and said my regulator must be bad. So I dug it up, and found it's one I've never seen. It doesn't have a screw/bolt on top. It could have broken off, but it's hard to tell with the dirt. There is something that looks like it could turn, if you had a special star/hex/torx/allen bit.

In general, it looks similar to a [SharkBite 3/4 regulator](http://www.homedepot.com/buy/sharkbite-3-4-in-eb-35-double-direct-45-set-psi-275318.html#.T8ka6LFxLVk.link). I did make a letter P on top, right were it starts to curve down.

So any thoughts? Here is a picture of what I have now.

[image: Regulator that I have now]

Comment: Add your picture to [http://imgur.com/](http://imgur.com/) and then post the link.  Somebody here will add it to your post.

Comment: http://imgur.com/iASuX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the screw is missing and you're getting the lowest possible pressure as a result. If it were me, I'd just replace it if you're able to access the other side and clear away the water under it (why is there water under it?). With access to both sides, replacing it is an easy DIY job if you're comfortable cutting and soldering pipes.

Comment: It's in my meter box and it has been raining a lot. So, water just gets trapped there. From my understanding, I can just unscrew the old one, and put the new one in. The new one is threaded, so shouldn't have to solder anything...

Comment: @DjFarout Ok, I worried that you had a leak inside. Count yourself lucky if it unscrews easily. My old one had threads and the plumber soldered them anyway (grrrr).